# SMS not sent in journey with Entry Salesforce Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

I have a journey that triggers on new account created in SFMC (AccountID is contact key). Via SF data entry event I'm pushing Account.PhoneNumber as one of the fields. I have a SMS activity in that journey that should send SMS to that highlighted phone number.

Problem I have is that for new accounts that are not yet contacts in SFMC, mobile contact is not created and SMS is not sent, although on journey canvas SMS interactions is highlighted as sent (contacts pass it)

Does anyone encountered something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved with [August 2017 Marketing Cloud patch](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/august_2017_release/mobile_studio/).

Now Contacts who do not exist in MobileConnect prior to SMS send in a Journey, will be automatically added and also subscribed to the defined keyword.

> For each SMS activity created, you can honor an existing SMS subscription or subscribe contacts’ phone numbers in real-time to a keyword of your choice as they hit the activity.