# For the life of me... SMS messages will not send in my Journey

Tags: journeybuilder, mobileconnect

I have a Journey where we send (or are trying to send) an SMS for those records that have a mobile phone in the Entry Source DE, and we can't seem to get anything to send.

We've researched high and low, to no avail.

- We selected "Use phone number attribute from Entry Source"
- We selected "Subscribe all contacts to a keyword" and nothing was sent
- We tried "Send only to contacts who are subscribed currently" and nothing was sent
- The mobile number was imported into Mobile Connect (and verified the # is there) but nothing was sent
- We ensured the mobile number includes the country code (in this case, 1)
- We see that records pass through the SMS activity, but no SMS is sent

Posts I've read ([SMS not sent in Journey](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175657/sms-not-sent-in-journey-with-entry-salesforce-data)) suggested a patch in August 2017 should address our use case, but nothing is sending.  Another post suggests the import of Mobile numbers into Mobile Connect ([how to use mobile connect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193039/how-to-use-mobile-connect-sms-in-journey-builder)), but still nothing sends

I'm at a total loss here... what could it be?!?!?!

Comment: Can you send regular SMS via MobileConnect outbound message to that Contact? Is the Contact in Active status with a keyword subscription as opt-in? Have you tried other Contacts with different numbers? Does your long-code support sending to that country?

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up questions.

The message is triggered via a Journey (Interaction), so I haven't tested it as a regular SMS message.

The contact is Active.

The contact is not subscribed to the Keyword, but the Journey setting is "Subscribe all contacts to a Keyword" and we selected a keyword

The short-code is supported in our country.

Comment: Check under this Contact engagement it shows that SMS was sent and not delivered or if it's now displaying anything about it. You can try sending a simple outbound SMS to that Contact in MobileConnect after you've opted it manually for that keyword. Later you can opt it out again for having the Journey Builder SMS activity subscribe it back again if this test passes.